# How to get 2 database tables and display only the 5 latest records? Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I need to get the latest activity from the database and order them by `created_at`.

There is a database table of `orders`, which has a `shop_id`, and there is a database table of `collected_birthdays`, which also has a `shop_id` incommon.

How to get the latest `orders` and `collected_birthdays` which has the same `shop_id` and take 5 latest records?

The mission is to display to the user the latest records of the two database tables, in the future, there will be more tables which will I need to display and get the latest 5 records.

Currently I found it make it work this way:

```
$shop = Shop::FindOrFail(1);

$orders = $shop->orders()->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->limit(5)->get();
$collectedBirthdays = $shop->collectedBirthdays()->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->limit(5)->get();

$latestActivity = $orders->merge($collectedBirthdays)->sortByDesc('created_at')->take(5);
```

This is not the best solution, but made it work.

Comment: You need to at least provide us with the schema of your tables.

Comment: What is it that you are asking for? Laravel code or the SQL? And what did you try so far?

Comment: @omarjayed I tried joining the tables. I would preffer a laravel query, not raw SQL query.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Getting the latest five records per table? Getting the latest five records of any table?

Comment: @NicoHaase 
 Getting the latest five records of any table

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DB::raw()`. It will take the raw query and give you the reault.

```
$data = DB::raw(
    'Select o.shop_id, o.created_at, cb.shop_id, cb.created_at
    From orders as o
    Inner Join collected_birthdays as cb on cb.shop_id = o.shop_id
    Order By o.created_at DESC      -- or use cb.created_at
    Limit 5;'
)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use take function in eloquent and do something like this:

```
Shop::join('orders', 'orders.shop_id', '=', 'shops.id')->orderBy('orders.created_at', 'DESC')->take(5)->get()
```

Or if you want to stop using join(table, onCondition..) I recommend you use Eloquent Power Joins package which will automatically generate joins for you based on relationship declared inside your model and use it like this:

```
Shop::joinRelationship('orders')->orderBy('orders.created_at', 'DESC')->take(5)->get();
```

Link to package: https://github.com/kirschbaum-development/eloquent-power-joins

This would also be possible by using paginate()